# Tensorflow Nan, where am I wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, regression

I am new in TF so please pardon me. 
My task is to create a model predicting some continuous numbers based on 90 features(later on I will reduce them to 57). I saw this example in internet - 'Boston house price prediction' and looked very similar to what I need. However I knew I will have troubles (because a model cannot be so easily adopted) and now the troubles  are, that I am having a Nan as a estimated value.
My code looks as following:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X_train = np.genfromtxt('data/train500X.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
Y_train = np.genfromtxt('data/train500Y.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
X_test = np.genfromtxt('data/test100X.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
Y_test = np.genfromtxt('data/test100Y.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float)

total_len = X_train.shape[0]
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 500
batch_size = 10
display_step = 1
dropout_rate = 0.9
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 90  # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 200  # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 200
n_hidden_4 = 256
n_input = X_train.shape[1]
n_classes = 1

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, 90])
y = tf.placeholder("float32", [None])

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0, 0.1)),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0, 0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.transpose(pred) - y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(total_len / batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch - 1):
            batch_x = X_train[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_y = Y_train[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]

            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                                   y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            c += c / total_batch
            # print(c) #c = nan???? total_batch = 50
            # print("what is here")
            # print(tf.is_finite(c, name=None))

        # sample prediction
        label_value = batch_y
        estimate = p
        err = label_value - estimate
        print("num batch:", total_batch)

        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", \
                  "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
            print("[*]----------------------------")
            for i in range(3):
                print("label value:", label_value[i], \
                      "estimated value:", estimate[i])
            print("[*]============================")
    exit()
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(S, "float32"))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: Y_test}))
```

A line of my train data looks like this: (train500X.csv)

```
0,1,1,1,1,0,20,36,4194304,8,7,1,4,3420,79691776,528594,3191,525403,349114,176,7,0.47922,0.700034,84.54,0,1,14.68,0,0,0,0,0,11215940,5091688,31.22,0,0,0,72,0,0,0,4,1000000000,4,17179869184,2133000000,4194300,0,0,57.14,0,3.39,37.52,0,0,0,0,0,61645484,4206508,6.39,33.49,213.6,40881.085,7,0,0,0,4,2500000000,8,68719476736,2133000000,8388604,0,0,0,752.51953125,2463.5,5523,46881,54734,1146164,194866,0.001020011479174,10.90673828125,0,1529.19102,367799.963702
```

A line of my labels data looks like this: (train500Y.csv)

```
24407
```

Output:

```
num batch: 50
Epoch: 0017 cost= 0.000000000
[*]----------------------------
label value: 7228.0 estimated value: [ nan]
label value: 43743.0 estimated value: [ nan]
label value: 15087.0 estimated value: [ nan]
[*]============================
```

Thank you in advance!
Any guidelines and suggestions will be considered.

P.S. If you have a better idea or examples I can learn from please recommend me.

Comment: I found out that the problem is coming because of my data being not normalized and the variation of the numbers is very big. However if anyone can give me ideas how to make my model better always here and listening :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the data normalization